# Argparse optional stdin read and/or stdout out

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, argparse

A non-Python program will call a Python program with both input and output arguments. Input may be a file reference or a string redirected to stdin in the non-Python program. Output may be a file or stdout.

`argparse.FileType` seems ready to handle this as it already has the special `-` to direct to stdin/stdout. In fact, using `-` to direct to stdout works but the implementation/syntax for stdin is what I don't know.

Examples calls in the non-Python code:
`python mycode.py - output.txt`
`python mycode.py - -`

What does the non-Python code do after that? Print/stdout an input string?
What does the Python code do after that?

I will always need to distinguish where both args are going (i.e. input and output) so using `default="-"` nor `default=sys.stdin` in `add_argument` won't work because they require an absent argument.

Here's what I have so far:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('read_fref', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('write_fref', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
parser_ns = parser.parse_args()

with parser_ns.read_fref as f_r:
    read_f = json.load(f_r)    

output = {'k': 'v'}

with parser_ns.write_fref as f_w:
    json.dump(output, f_w)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.  I understand what Python and `argparse` are doing, but I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Your sample looks like it would run fine when called from a Linux shell.  With the the `-` arguments, it should accept input from the keyboard, and display it on the screen.  But those arguments are most often used with shell redirection controls `>, <, |` (details vary with shell, `sh`, `bash`, etc).

But if you are using the shell to redirect `stdin` or `stdout` to/from files, you could just as well give those files as commandline arguments.

If you are bothered by required/default issue, consider making these arguments flagged (also called `optionals`):

```
parser.add_argument('-r','--readfile', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-')
parser.add_argument('-w','--writefile', type=argparse.FileType('w'), default='-')
```

With this change, these calls are the same

```
python mycode.py -r - <test.json
python mycode.py <test.json
python mycode.py -r test.json
```

all writing to the screen (stdout).  That could be redirected in similar ways.

To take typed input:

```
python mycode.py
{...}
^D
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The non-Python code would like the option to pass the input as a string passed within it's own code. So the input would not be coming from the keyboard. That code prefers not to have to write that string to file then read that file in. Also, the "default" approach you mention won't work for the reasons I stated above.

Comment: I think you need to give a concrete example of how the non-Python code calls this script.  Be clear whether it calls Python directly or via a shell.

Comment: `default` works if the `argparse` argument is optional, i.e. not required.

Comment: The code and calls you have suggested work to receive input from stdin, but how would I output to a file and not stdout? Also, how would I input from a file, not from stdin? I tried it in Windows cmd a few ways but couldn't get either to work.

Comment: My examples show how to get input from `test.json` file.  A variation on your original works for output `python mycode.py -w output.txt`.  I don't recall if Windows `cmd` has `<`,`>` redirection like `bash` or not.

Comment: OK, got it. Tried all the variations I need including read stdin, write stdout:

Comment: OK, got it. Tried all the variations I need including read stdin, write stdout: `test.py -r - -w - <in.txt` and read stdin, write to file: `test.py -r - -w out.txt <in.txt`. Thanks for your time!